# What is and isn't a constituent, and how (whether?) can one argue that something is or isn't grammatical

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverbials, constituents

**Background**

In [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) on p. 1317, we find the following analysis of the sentence

[1] *[Beauty] [as well as love] is redemptive.*

They note that the singular *is* signifies that *as well as* is here not a coordinator (like it is in e.g. *[Abstraction] [as well as impressionism] **were** Russian inventions.*). In fact, CGEL says that in [1],

> *as well as* does not form a constituent. This is evident from the fact that *as well* can occur on its own: compare *Beauty is
>   redemptive and love is as well*. In [1], then, the second *as* is a
>   preposition taking the NP *love* as its complement, and the whole PP
>   *as love* is  an indirect complement in the AdvP *as well as love*.

This argument assumes that

[2] *Beauty is redemptive and love is as well*

is (for a lack of a better term---what is the right term, by the way?) a 'syntactic equivalent' of [1].

**My question 1**

Here is my initial attempt to formulate my question: what does the analysis used by CGEL say about

[3] *?He as well as they is going to L.A.*

I'm putting the '?' because [3] sounds dubious to me. If [3] is to have any chance of being grammatical, *as well as they* must be interpretable as an AdvP (because if *as well as* is interpreted as a coordinator, then we need a plural verb: ***are*** going to L.A.). And if I'm following the reasoning in CGEL correctly, the AdvP interpretation would imply that [3] has the following 'syntactic equivalent':

[4] *He **is** going to L.A. and they **are** as well.*

This case is different from the one in CGEL because in [1], both *beauty* and *love* are singular, and so in the 'syntactic equivalent' [2] they both get the **same** (singular) form of the verb. In contrast, in [3] *he* is singular, but *they* is plural. So in [4] we must have the singular *is* for *he*, but the plural *are* for *they*. Given this difference, can we still say that [4] is a 'syntactic equivalent' of [3]? What is it that really matters when making this sort of an argument?

**My question 2**

What I would really want to do is present the following argument.

1. [4] is obviously grammatical.
2. [3] is a 'syntactic equivalent' of [4].
3. Therefore, [3] is grammatical.

I suspect that the answer is **no**---that there is no way to use grammar to predict whether some tricky sentence is grammatical or not. I would think that all you can do is this: once you already know (from analyzing corpora etc.) whether something is grammatical, *then* you can show that the reason for it being grammatical or not is that it does or doesn't conform to some rule of grammar. But 'rules of grammar' cannot help you with controversial cases. The only way is to know whether a controversial case is grammatical is to ask (a lot of) native speakers whether it sounds acceptable to them or not.

Is that correct?

**Summary**

To summarize, my questions are:

A. Is [3], in fact, grammatical?

B. *In general*, does the type of argument I presented above (1.-2.-3. in **My question 2**) work? *In general*, is that a legitimate way to argue
    that something is grammatical? (Let's assume there are no idiomatic expressions 'anywhere near', i.e. that there are no relevant idioms that could complicate matters.)

C. This question is about whether it matters that both *is* and *are* are present in [4], but only *is* is present in [3]. Here I'm not really asking about the particular sentences [3] and [4], but rather about whether, when making the **type** of argument CGEL makes when it analyzes [1] with the help of [2], it would matter if the form of the verb in the 'syntactic equivalent' changes. Imagine there is a sentence kind of like [3], but indisputably grammatical, and also a corresponding sentence like [4]. Suppose that in the latter sentence there are both *is* and *are*, whereas in the former, there is only *is*. Does this fact, in and of itself, make it impossible to use the latter sentence for the purpose of syntactic analysis of the former (such as finding out whether something is a  constituent of the former)? To put it another way: even if [3] isn't grammatical, *imagine* it were. Could in that case one use [4] to argue that *as well as* isn't a constituent of [3]? Or would this argument be invalidated by the fact that both *is* and *are* are present in [4], whereas only *is* is present in [3]?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> [1] Beauty as well as love is redemptive

is not the syntactic equivalent of

> [2] Beauty is redemptive and love is as well.

As *CGEL* points out, sentence 1 is a single clause

> NP (Subject) + AdvP + Copular V + Adjective (Predicate Comp)

Sentence 2 is a doubled compound clause in which the first component is

> [1a] NP (Subj) + Copular V + Adjective (Predicate Comp)

and the second is

> [1b] NP (Subj) +  Copular V + Adverbial PP

1 and 2 are semantic equivalents, not syntactic. I would say that

> [3a] He, as well as they, is going to L.A.

is an example of *syllepsis*, a construction in which one word is understood to be associated with two syntactic elements in a way that would not be acceptable for one of the elements standing alone.  For example, the following would be acceptable:

> He sticks to his story; I, to mine

even though *sticks* is the wrong person for use with *I*.

In 3a, the one word is *is*, the two elements are *He* and *they*, and the unacceptable parse is *they is going*. I inserted the commas to indicate how someone would parse the sentence upon hearing it. A parallel  explanation can be constructed for

> [3b] He as well as, they are going to L.A.

The one word is now *are*, the two syntactic elements are still *He* and *they*, and the forbidden standalone element is *He are going*.  The reason this sounds wrong is that the attraction of the third person plural personal pronoun to its verb *are* is likely to lead a listener down the garden path parse indicated by the comma in 3b.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have several questions, but I'll start with this one: why is it legitimate to use [2] to analyze what is and what isn't a constituent of [1]?

Comment: Also, how should one describe the relation between [1] and [2]? You say that 'syntactic equivalence' is too strong. But 'semantic equivalence' is too weak, because I can construct semantically equivalent sentences whose syntax is so different that they cannot be used to analyze one another syntactically. So [2] is not only semantically equivalent to [1]; it is also somehow closely syntactically related in just the right way. Is there a term for such a relation?

Comment: Finally (for now): is [3] gramamtical _as written_, without the commas?

Comment: Let me try to make the question in my first comment at least a bit more specific---I know it's awfully broad at the moment: assuming [3] is grammatical, is it legitimate to use [4] to analyze what is and what isn't a constituent of [3]? Apparently, the sudden appearance of _are_ does not make such analysis illegitimate. But what sorts of things _would_ make it illegitimate? What is it that really matters?

Comment: @linguisticturn *why is it legitimate to use [2] to analyze what is and what isn't a constituent of [1]?* The claim is that *as well as* in [1] isn't a constituent, i.e., a coherent syntactic unit, and the evidence for this is that in [2] *as well* stands alone as a constituent.  In fact, it has the same meaning in both [1] and [2], i.e. *and additionally*.

Comment: @linguisticturn I should insert here the warning that I'm not a grammarian or a linguist.  I only pretend to be on ELU, so forewarned is forearmed.  I don't think [2] is closely syntactically related to [1], so I don't think [2] can help to syntactically analyze [1], except insofar as it [2] uses constituents in the same way as [1].  [2] uses its verbs differently, so it's not much help on the verb front.  [2] has the same use for *as well* though.

Comment: @linguisticturn *is [3] grammatical as written, without the commas?*  It depends on what you mean by "grammatical"?  It uses syllepsis, which is commonly found to excuse technical violation of grammatical rules.

Comment: @linguisticturn *is it legitimate to use [4] to analyze what is and what isn't a constituent of [3]?* Yes, but I don't think this as anything to do with the fact that [4] is a rephrasing of [3].  If you're unsure of whether a group of words forms a coherent syntactic unit, you may look for guidance from any other sentence using that same group for the same meaning.

Comment: Yes, but how do we know in the first place that the 'as well' in [2] is "the same" as the 'as well' in [1] (i.e. that it is 'the same group with the smae meaning')? All we really know is that there is something different about the 'as well's in [1] and in 'Abstraction as well as impressionism were Russian inventions' (let's call this latter sentence [A]): after all, if they were the same, we'd need a plural verb in [1].

Comment: But now watch what CGEL does next: it says that the difference between the 'as well's in [1] and [A] is that 'as well as' is a constituent in [A] but not in [1]. And CGEL's evidence for this assertion is  that 'as well' appears alone in [2]. Thus, CGEL's argument **assumes**, rather than **proves**, that the 'as well' in [1] is the same as the one in [2]. So: how do we know that this assumption of CGEL's is true? To repeat, all we know is that 'as well' in [1] is not like the 'as well' in [A]; but why does this imply that therefore the 'as well' in [1] must be like the 'as well' in [2]?

Comment: @linguisticturn I've read that passage a dozen times, and I'll have to admit defeat.  Here's the best I can do.  *As well as* can be a syntactic unit (a coordinator) when it does comparison:  *They live as well as love*.  That is, they're as good at living as they are as loving.  But it can also act an an adjunct when other clues in the sentence preclude coordination: *Beauty as well as love is redemptive*.  Here the clue is the singular verb.  If we replace *as well as* with the coordinator *and* to produce an equivalent sentence, *as well* can appear on its own as a unit unlike *as well as*.

Comment: @linguisticturn You're welcome. I wish I'd been able to clarify things more.

Answer (score 1):

A. No (matter of fact); B. No (confuses fact and theory); C. I don't understand the question.

When I need to be careful, I understand *acceptability* to be a matter of fact -- how naive native speakers judge sentences -- and *grammaticality* to be a matter of theory -- what does a given grammatical theory predict about acceptability.  This is partially in agreement with what Chomsky proposed in **Aspects of the Theory of Syntax**, when he says that *grammatical* means "generated by a given grammar".  Grammars are (often incorrect) theories of a language.

(Since others don't usually use "grammatical" in this sense, and I don't always need to be careful, I often use "grammatical" to characterize facts, just for the sake of communicating.  Often, people don't seem to distinguish between fact and theory.)

For your question B., you start with a matter of fact (which should read "[4] is obviously acceptable"), use a theory to derive 2., then draw a theoretical conclusion in 3.