# Is there a grammatical mistake in this sentence:- The owner as well as his servants is honest.?

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatical error in the following sentence:- 
The owner as well as his servants is honest.

Comment: The construction is disjointed (in my view) both grammatically and conceptually. The mind has to go down one avenue, then halt and examine a cul-de-sac. I would far rather read 'Both the owner and his servants are honest'. It avoids the hiatus of a plural noun beside a singular verb and does not require any punctuation.

Comment: Many (including me) would argue that the sentence is correct in a grammatical sense, though you might want to add commas around the dependent clause. But you would be well served to recast it as "The owner and his servants are honest".

Comment: Google Books contains ***no*** relevant instances of [*the owner and his staff **is***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+owner+and+his+staff+is%22+-%22of+the+owner+and+his+staff+is%22), but they claim over 100 instances of [*the owner and his staff **are**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+owner+and+his+staff+are%22+-%22of+the+owner+and+his+staff+are%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That seems irrelevant, since the question asks about the construction "the owner **as well as** his X is" not "the owner **and** his X is".

Comment: @FumbleFingers it's not over 100 examples it's just over **twenty** for [the owner and his staff are](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+owner+and+his+staff+are%22&num=20&tbm=bks&ei=ym3fWuybA4W80wKOl4eIDQ&start=20&sa=N&biw=1312&bih=619&dpr=1.1). You're too trusting, you should check Google Books' estimates by clicking on the results below.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: It wouldn't affect the validity of my point if there were only actually a dozen instances. Zero compared to anything more than an insignificant handful still makes a convincing usage distinction to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you continually cite the first estimates of Google Books as proof of the validity of your comments, twenty instances is far less impressive than over a 100 of them. Google's estimates are very often way off the charts and you know it. I've brought this point up with you more than once.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: So have several others over the years. But the fact remains that when there are ***no*** instances of what I consider an "unacceptable" construction, whether there are  10, 20, or 100 instances of an "acceptable" one doesn't affect the validity of the implication made by citing those figures. Face it, you're just nit-picking.

Comment: Face it @FumbleFingers you never like to be seen as someone who "could" be wrong as seen in many multiple instances, unless the person who's correcting you is a man, or someone you really respect. I am neither of the two.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Dang! You're spiky today! Where did that idea of misogyny come from? Lighten up, please. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers this is one [instance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185828/why-is-it-have-someone-wrapped-around-your-little-finger#comment666770_185828) along with several others. That's where I got it from.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Gimmie a break! Should I have asked about ***he's** got **her** wrapped around **his** finger* to avoid accusations of misogyny? I genuinely don't understand where all this bile is coming from, and I can assure you I'm not *intentionally* doing anything to justify it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers oh don't be silly. You think I'm talking about the use of the masculine or feminine pronoun, seriously? Then you are absolutely clueless as to what I am referring to. P.S. *unless the person who's correcting you is a man, or someone you really respect.* I did not exclude the possibility that you might respect a woman. I said I was neither a man nor someone you respected.

Answer (score 1):

There are errors in both construction and subject-verb agreement. As I see it, there are two essential ways of correctly phrasing this:

> 1. The **owner**, as well as his servants, **is** honest.

Here, I have added commas. That makes *as well as his servants* a non-restrictive phrase. It's something that adds information but which is not required. (I could have used parentheses instead of commas.) With this, grammar applies to the sentence as if it weren't there. In other words, *the **owner is** honest*.

But while technically correct, it is still awkward.

> 2. The **owner as well as his servants are** honest.

Here, I have changed **is** to **are**. There is now a plural subject (**owner as well as his servants**) and a plural verb (**are**).

But it, too, is awkward.

Normally, you want to phrase a sentence so that it sounds correct both with and without a non-restrictive phrase, and without having to struggle to identify and validate subjects with verbs.

In this case, the use of **as well as** is used in an uncommon way. I would rephrase it in an unambiguous way:

> The owner and his servants are honest.
>   Both the owner and his servants are honest.
>   The owner, like his servants, is honest.
>   The owner is honest. So are his servants.

Comment: I agree with almost everything you say (and thus am upvoting this answer) except for one quibble: your first solution makes *as well as servants* not an **appositive** but rather a **supplement**, something that is not integrated into the syntactical structure of the sentence. This is especially obvious from the fact that it can be put in parentheses. Unfortunately, I don't know of a good discussion of supplements that is open access. All I can say is that [CGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468) has an extensive discussion of them on pp. 1350-1362.

Comment: The following two links might be helpful, though: [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&lpg=PP1&dq=Huddleston%20Student's&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q=supplement&f=false) and [this](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html) (the section (b) Supplementary relative clauses.) They don't adress exactly our case, but will give you an idea of what is meant by 'supplements'.

Comment: @linguisticturn Hmm. Except that appositives can be put within parentheses (or dashes)—so the punctuation itself is not a good indicator. I do agree, however,  that there are both restrictive and non-restrictive appositives, something which I didn't distinguish. I haven't heard the term **supplement** before, so that's interesting. (Perhaps we're talking about the same thing but with different verbiage. I wonder if it's a regional difference between the UK and North America . . .)

Comment: Yes, we are sort of talking about the same thing. CGEL distinguishes the **semantic** property of being *restrictive* or *nonrestrictive* from the **syntactical** property of being *integrated* or *nonintegrated (supplemental)*. In particular, in disagreement with traditional grammar, CGEL says that 'integrated construction is not necessarily semantically restrictive'. They say this because of examples like *This is my husband George*, which does not convey that the speaker has more than one husband even though *my husband* is syntactically integrated.

Comment: And it is also true that appositives can be both integrated and supplementary, as in: [1] a. *They are working on a new production of the **opera** ͟'͟C͟a͟r͟m͟e͟n͟'͟*. [modifier]  b. ***Bizet's most popular opera,** '͟C͟a͟r͟m͟e͟n͟'͟, was first produced in 1875.* [supplement]. 'In [1a] the appositive *Carmen* is a modifier of *opera*, identifying which opera is being referred to, while in [1b] it is a supplement to the anchor NP *Bizet's most popular opera*, and since there can be only one entity satisfying that description the supplement is again non-restrictive.'

Comment: However, *as well as his servants* is nevertheless not an appositive. The definition of an appositive is this: 'Appositive dependents are ones which when substituted for the matrix NP in a declarative clause systematically yield a clause which is an entailment of the original'. For example, *She sang in [the opera 'Carmen']* entails *She sang in 'Carmen'*; *It was founded in [the year 1850]* entails *It was founded in 1810*, etc. These were integrated appositives, but the same story with supplemental ones: *The first contestant, Lulu, was ushered on stage* entails *Lulu was ushered on stage.*

Comment: But note that this definition implies that appositives must be noun phrases (NPs). Thus *as well as his servants* cannot be an appositive; *The owner, as well as his servants, is honest* does not entail * *as well his servants is honest*, because the latter isn't even grammatical.

Comment: @linguisticturn Right . . . I changed **appositive** in my answer to "non-restrictive phrase." ;)

Answer (score 1):

The controversy here is about the singular form of the verb *is*, namely, wheather one must change it to the plural form *are*. The plural form is definitely acceptable here; the question is whether the singular form might be acceptable, too.

Considering the *is* version: on the one hand, it seems there are completely analogous sentences, with verbs in their singular forms, that are definitely acceptable (see below, esp. [70] ii a.). On the other hand, as Jason observed, in the case of your sentence, the *is* version sounds a bit off. I don't know for sure what the reason is, but I have a guess: the fact that *servants* is in the plural. I'll return to that after providing a bit of background.

**The grammar**

Here is the relevant section of [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (pp. 1316-1317):

> ■ *As well as*
>
> The literal use of *as well as* is seen in comparisons of equality like *He played a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ ͟h͟e͟'͟d͟ ͟e͟v͟e͟r͟ ͟d͟o͟n͟e͟*. Here *well* is an adverb heading the underlined phrase, an adjunct of manner. There is also an idiomatic use meaning approximately "and, in addition to", illustrated in:
>
> [70] i a. *She [means what she says] [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ says what she means]*. 
>              b. *[Abstraction] [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ impressionism] were Russian inventions.* 
>              c. *[Both increasing ewe liveweight,] [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ liveweightat mating,] influence*
>                    *ovulation rate and lambing performance.* 
>           ii a. *[Beauty] [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ love] is redemptive.* 
>              b. *He will have, [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ the TV stations,] [a book publishing empire].* 
>              c. *J met her father, [whom] she had invited along [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ her college friends].* 
>              d. *She [has experience in management], [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ being an actor of talent].*
>
> In [i] *as well as* behaves like the coordinator *and*. In [ia] it links two finite VPs [verb phrases], a property characteristic of coordinators: cf. property (c) of §2.1 ['Wide range of categories that can be coordinated']. Note in this connection that while *She plays t͟h͟e͟ ͟p͟i͟a͟n͟o͟ as well as t͟h͟e͟ ͟v͟i͟o͟l͟i͟n͟* (with paired NPs [noun phrases]) is ambiguous between a literal meaning ("as proficiently") and the idiomatic one ("and"), *She p͟l͟a͟y͟s͟ ͟t͟h͟e͟ ͟p͟i͟a͟n͟o͟ as well as s͟i͟n͟g͟s͟ ͟l͟i͟e͟d͟e͟r͟* (with paired finite VPs) has only the idiomatic meaning. In [ib] the form *were* indicates that the subject NP is plural, just like *abstraction and impressionism*. And in [ic] we have not only such plural agreement, but also a correlative pairing of *both* with *as well as* instead of the usual *and*.
>
> In [70ii], by contrast, *as well as* behaves markedly differently from a coordinator. In [iia] the 3rd person singular verb-form *is* indicates that this time the subject is singular: is agrees with *beauty*, so that *as well as love* is treated syntactically as an adjunct, not a coordinate. In [iib] *as well as the TV stations* precedes *a book publishing empire*, making it clearly an adjunct. *And* could not appear in the position *as well as* has here: cf. property (d) of §2.1 ['Impossibility of fronting an expanded coordinate': A coordinator and its coordinate cannot be moved to front position. Note here the 
>   contrast between the coordinator *but* and the preposition *although*: 
>   *He joined the club b͟u͟t͟ he had little spare time* is OK; <sup>*</sup>*B͟u͟t͟ he had little spare time he joined the club* is not. In contrast, both of the following subordinating constructions are OK: *He joined the club a͟l͟t͟h͟o͟u͟g͟h͟ he had little spare time*; *A͟l͟t͟h͟o͟u͟g͟h͟ he had little spare time he joined the club* This restriction reflects the fact that the coordinates are of equal status]. In [iic] relativisation has applied to just one of the bracketed constituents, contrary to coordinator property (e) ['Across the board application of syntactic processes': A special consequence of the requirement that coordinates be syntactically alike is that certain syntactic processes must apply **across the board**, i.e. to each one of the coordinates]. And in [iid] the bracketed constituents are syntactically unlike, the first being a finite VP, the second a gerund-participial, contrary to coordinator property (b) ['Coordinates must be syntactically alike']. Note that order reversal is possible in [iid] (*As well as being an actor of talent, she has experience of management*), but not in [ia] (<sup>*</sup>*As well as says what she means, she means what she says*).
>
> We must conclude that idiomatic *as well as* can be construed syntactically in two  ways, introducing an element that is either coordinate (as in [70i]) or subordinate (as in [ii]). In the former case, we take it to have been reanalysed as a compound coordinator. In the latter case there has been no such syntactic reanalysis, and here *as well as* does not form a constituent. This is evident from the fact that *as well* can occur on its own: compare *Beauty is redemptive and love is as well.* In [iia], then, the second *as* is a preposition taking the NP *love* as its complement, and the whole PP [preposition phrase] *as love* is an indirect complement in the AdvP [adverb phrase] *as well as love*. Similarly for the other examples in [ii].
>
> As a coordinator, *as well as* is restricted to subclausal coordination: *She plays the piano as well as she sings lieder*, for example, has only the literal comparative interpretation. Even as a coordination, '*X as well as Y*' differs from '*X and Y*' in that the second term is backgrounded: *Y* often expresses information that is discourse-old, i.e. familiar from the prior discourse.

I should say that I have some misgivings about CGEL's argument for the claim that *as well as* is not a constituent in [70] ii; see my discussion with the user deadrat in the comments to his answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318618/what-is-and-isnt-a-constituent-and-how-whether-can-one-argue-that-something).

However, regardless of what is ultimately the correct grammatical analysis of the sentences in [70] ii, it is clear that both of the following are acceptable (note the *were* in i b. and *is* in ii a.):

[70] i b. *[Abstraction] [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ impressionism] **were** Russian inventions.* 
        ii a. *[Beauty] [a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ love] **is** redemptive.*

**Back to your sentence**

So, by analogy with [70] i b. and ii a., one would *think* that both of the following are acceptable too:

[1] a. *The owner a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ his servants **are** honest.*
      b. <sup>?</sup>*The owner a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ his servants **is** honest.*

And yet, in the case of [1], the version b. sounds off, at least to my ear (as well as that of Jason). My guess is that this is because *servants* is in the plural, and the proximity of the plural noun to the verb makes it harder to swallow the verb being in the singular (despite the fact that the subject is *the owner*). Let's try it out:

[2] *The owner a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ his servant **is** honest.*

To my ear, if [2] is pronounced with the right prosody, e.g. with *well* sort of emphasized so that the meaning is *His servant is not the only one who is honest; the owner is honest, too*, then [2] is acceptable.

Finally, as Jason suggested, one can also make *as well as his servants* into a **supplement** (see [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), pp. 1350-1362) by offseting it with commas (or in some other way):

[3] a. *The owner, a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ his servants, is honest.*
       b. *The owner—a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ his servants—is honest.*
       b. *The owner (a͟s͟ ͟w͟e͟l͟l͟ ͟a͟s͟ his servants) is honest.*

Comment: I really don't think "the owner as well as his servants are"  is uncontroversial. If you put in the parenthetical commas after *owner* and *servants*, it is plainly wrong; without them it may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: @TimLymington 1. Putting any sort of extra marks totally changes the syntax, so it says little about the version without such marks. 2. Of course that given the right context, almost anything can be made unacceptable. But the point is that one does not have to search hard for a context in which *the owner as well as his servants are honest* is fine.  Imagine you walk up to a complete stranger (who is a native speaker) in the street and ask, 'Hey, what are your thoughts about this: the owner as well as his servants are honest?' The stranger will be confused—**but not about the grammar**.